# Module parse failed: Unexpected token. You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs, webpack-dev-server

I get the following error below and I don't understand the reason I think there should be something with babel. I use web-dev-server and babel. Its in react.

```
ERROR in ./App.js 188:13
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (188:13)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| //console.log(filter);
| if(isHomePage)
| return
| return (
| <div className={'App ${isDetailPage ? 'detail-page' : 'landing-page'} '}

@ ./main.js 1:0-27
@ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 ./main.js

ERROR in ./Home.js 34:8
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (34:8)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| render() {
| return (
| <div className={App}>
| hello
|
@ ./main.js 2:0-29
@ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 ./main.js
i ?wdm?: Failed to compile.
```

My Webconfig file looks like this:

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    entry: './main.js',
    output: { path: __dirname, filename: 'bundle.js' },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /.jsx?$/,
                include: [
                    path.resolve(__dirname, 'path/to/imported/file/dir')
                ],
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                query: {
                    presets: ['es2015', 'react']
                }
            }
        ]
    },
}
```

My package.json file looks like this:

```
"dependencies": {
    "missing": "0.0.1",
    "react": "^0.14.7",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.7",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.5",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.3.13",
    "webpack": "^4.27.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

What am I missing here? is that something related to path.resolve?

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered the same problem, in my case problem was related with regex. Regex definition was wrong. I suggest you to check any regex inside main.js.